# Monitor or prevent? DLP

Tags: data-leakage, monitoring, dlp

### **Scenario:**

I'm administrating my company's network all alone. I'm the only IT guy around and can not spend too much time with anything special as some people would start freaking out.
I have to implement some DLP(Data Leaking/Loss Prevention) system and I have to decide whether to focus on monitoring or preventing it.

**Monitoring:**
*PROS:* No false positives.
*CONS:* Lack of time will cause data being leaked and me realising a two days later.

**Peventing:**
*PROS:* No data leaked (if properly configured)
*CONS:* False positives and configuration and reconfiguration of filters

---

So far, I'm in favour of *Monitoring* as the other option would lead in *false positives = mad people*

Anyone could throw some light in here? What should I do regarding my scenario?

Comment: @Matthew I'd like to get an answer for my specific scenario + the answer to that question is 100% subjective (doesn't mean I don't agree with him) and would like to read some objective posts.

Comment: As it stands, your question invites debate and discussion, which doesn't really fit the Q&A format of this site. The specific decision would depend on your company requirements - if you have regulatory requirements to prevent data loss, you might not have a choice. For commercial systems, the difference may be an option within the software itself.

Comment: @Matthew I think it's good question and I think there's suitable answer, pls see and comment below

Comment: @Matthew the scenario I presented is what matters here, no restrictions from my company or anything similar. I just "need" the answer for theoretical reasons

Comment: if you don't want burgled, do you never leave the house, or do you invest in preventing break-ins?

Comment: It will probably depend on the amount of risk your organization can accept. I agree with @Matthew, it's too broad...

Answer (score 1):

You should focus on both, but not only, monitoring and preventing is part of single system where there are also established procedures on what to do if the data is leaked or lost.

1. Monitoring (e.g. data availability, data leaks via audits)
2. Taking action (procedures) in case of breach or data loss

   - Sending notifications to interested parties
   - Restoring from backups
   - Failing over to another node
   - Failing over to another location
   - Etc
3. Preventing

   - managing access (granting users appropriate permissions)
   - ensuring policy (including backups and access policy, e.g. group policy)

Hope this helps.